# Input again if exception catched

Tags: c#, exception

I want to ask user to re-input, if exception cathced, but don't know how:

```
class Quadrilateral
{
    Point[] pointsArr = new Point[4];

    public Quadrilateral()
    {
        foreach (Point pointVar in pointsArr)
        {

            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input coordinates:");
                float x = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                float y = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

                }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Illegal value, please re-input");     
            }

        }
    }     
}
```

I think of using do-while loop, but have some problems with it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a normal **`while`** loop and increment the iterator variable only if there is no exception, thereby ensuring that you get input the exact number of times that you want. Use `continue` keyword to go to the next iteration, if any exception occurs.

I have used `Int` type for simplicity

```
        int[] pointsArr = new int[4];

        int arraySize = pointsArr.Length;
        int i = 0;
        while (i < arraySize)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Input coordinates:");
                float x = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
                float y = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Illegal value, please re-input");
                continue;
            }
            i++;
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
```